# how to make a decode key from an encode key (substitution cipher) C

Tags: c

the key for encoding is `"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"` which is the code you get when you enter `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` in the program. how do i make a decode key out of it.  this is a substitution cipher. if you have a suggestion please keep it simple and make use of the variables you have. no complicated or any library functions

```
    char * decodeSubstitution(char * lcEncodingKey, char * src, char * dest)
{
    char      lcDecodingKey[26];
    char      ucDecodingKey[26];





    char* deststart=dest;


    int i ;


    int offset1;
    int offset2;

    // Create the lower case decoding key from the lower case encoding key
    // (WRITE CODE HERE)
     for (i=0; i<26 ; i++){
     //    lcDecodingKey[i]=lcEncodingKey[i];
          lcDecodingKey[i]=

         ucDecodingKey[i]= toupper(lcDecodingKey[i]);
     }


    // Create the uppercase decoding
    // (WRITE CODE HERE)


    // Implementation of the generalized substitution decoder.
    // (WRITE CODE HERE)
    for (; *src; ++src, ++dest)
    {
      if (isupper(*src))
        {
            offset2=*src-'A';
            *dest=ucDecodingKey[offset2];

         }



         else if (islower(*src)){
              offset1 = *src - 'a';

       *dest = lcDecodingKey[offset1];
         } else{

             *dest=*src;
         }
    }
         *dest = '\0';

         return deststart;


}
```

thats the function for decoding.

Comment: Please, take more care when posting your code. Nothing screams "Help, I'm unable to do my homework and the deadline's today" like reams of `(WRITE CODE HERE)` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you encode, your substitution is a simple lookup in the encoding key `enc`:

```
cipher = enc[plain]
```

where `cipher` and `plain` are the indices f the lower-case letters from `a` (0) to `z` (25). When you decode, it's the other way round for the decoding key, `dec`:

```
plain = dec[cipher]
      = dec[enc[plain]]
```

Of course, `dec[enc[plain]]` must map to itself and you can create the decoding cipher from the encoding cipher like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    dec[enc[i]] = i;
}
```

which should give you

```
enc: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
dec: kxvmcnophqrszyijadlegwbuft
```

for your example: If you encode a `c` (index 2), it will become an `e`. If you decode that (or encode it with the decoding key), `e` (index 4) will become a `c` again.

(Of course, you must still map the ASCII characters to the natural indices 0 to 25. I'll leave that tom you.)

Comment: I don't exactly understand any of this. why are you treating chars like integers? can you explain what you did. especially the part with the for loop.

Comment: Er, I thought that you already had a routine to encode your string, no? And you already used `islower` and offset calculations. In C, a `char` is a small integer. If you don't know that, you should go back to studying your basics.